# painting a cork floor (previously coated with polyurethane varnish)

Tags: floor, paint

Our cork kitchen floor has a white stain and coated with 3 coats of polyurethane varnish two years ago. But the varnish has begun to wear through and the cork colour is visible.

We were never happy with the way the stained cork looked and now would like to paint over the floor with a solid colour.

What kind of paint should we use?

Should we be concerned that the cork is ever so slightly "squishy" and has a bit of "give", will a hard brittle paint crack under these conditions?

will there be any problems with painting over the previous varnish coating?

Comment: This strikes me as an awful, awful idea. I would advise you to not do it.

Comment: What type of polyurethane was used, and has it cracked at all?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do not think painting a floor would be a good idea. A solid color paint or stain will likely chip and wear unevenly. As in wherever your high traffic areas are will look awful in no time at all.

If you are to paint it you will need to sand the gloss of the previous coating. This glass will prevent any other paints or stains from correctly adhering to the surface. The same exact rule applies to painting a glossy wall or any other surface.